# Index not being used when column is part of composite key

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

I have two huge tables from which i have select huge amount of data.

Tables store Purchase Order Details and product information.

```
    PURCHASE_ORDER_DETAILS.
    CREATE TABLE `PURCHASE_ORDER_DETAILS` (
    `PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PF` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `PRODUCT_CODE_PF` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
    `ORDER_QUANTITY` INT(8) DEFAULT NULL,
    `UNIT_PRICE` DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ORDER_FULLFILLMENT_DUE_DATE` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `DELIVERY_ADDRESS` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `DELIVERY_CITY` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
     `DELIVERY_ZIP` BIGINT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `other columns`
      PRIMARY KEY (`PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PF`,`PRODUCT_CODE_PF`),
      KEY `RMAPWBTX_PUCH_ORDE_DLST_INDX` (`DELIVERY_STATE_ID_FK`),
      KEY `RMAPWBTX_PUCH_ORDE_DLTY_INDX` (`DELIVERY_TYPE_FK`),
      KEY `RMAPWBTX_PUCH_ORDE_TACO_INDX` (`TAX_CODE_FK`),
      KEY `RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PDCO_FK` (`PRODUCT_CODE_PF`),
      KEY `RMAPWBTX_PUOR_DETL_TACO_FK` (`TAX_CODE_FK`),
      KEY `CREATED_DATE_INDX` (`CREATED_DATE`),
      KEY `MODIFIED_DATE_INDX` (`MODIFIED_DATE`),
      CONSTRAINT `RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PDCO_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_CODE_PF`) 
      REFERENCES `PRODUCT` (`PRODUCT_CODE_PK`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PONU_FK` FOREIGN KEY 
      (`PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PF`) REFERENCES `PURCHASE_ORDER` 
      (`PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PK`),
     CONSTRAINT `RMAPWBTX_PO_DETL_DSID_FK` FOREIGN KEY 
     (`DELIVERY_STATE_ID_FK`) REFERENCES `STATE` (`STATE_ID_PK`),
     CONSTRAINT `RMAPWBTX_PUOR_DETL_TACO_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`TAX_CODE_FK`) 
     REFERENCES `TAX` (`TAX_CODE_PK`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
     ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


PRODUCT

    CREATE TABLE `PRODUCT` (
    `PRODUCT_CODE_PK` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
    `PRODUCT_DESC` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `FEE_BILL_CODE` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `other columns`
     PRIMARY KEY (`PRODUCT_CODE_PK`),
     KEY `CREATED_DATE_INDX` (`CREATED_DATE`),
     KEY `MODIFIED_DATE_INDX` (`MODIFIED_DATE`),
     KEY `PRODUCT_EXCO_FK` (`EXPENSE_CODE_ID_FK`),
     KEY `FK_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TYPE` (`ENTITY_TYPE_CODE_FK`),
     CONSTRAINT `FK_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`ENTITY_TYPE_CODE_FK`) REFERENCES `ENTITY_TYPE` (`ENTITY_TYPE_CODE_PK`)
     ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

     Below query is taking ~10min to get ~1M records.

     EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM
     PURCHASE_ORDER_DETAILS POD
     JOIN PRODUCT PRD ON POD.PRODUCT_CODE_PF=PRD.PRODUCT_CODE_PK;
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+-----------------

    -----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+-------+
    | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref                                           | rows  | Extra |
    +----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+-------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | PRD   | ALL  | PRIMARY                    | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                                          | 14283 | NULL  |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | POD   | ref  | RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PDCO_FK | RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PDCO_FK | 34      | REALREMIT_PROD_ALTISOURCE.PRD.PRODUCT_CODE_PK |    40 | NULL  |
    +----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+---
```

Edit1:
Above query was an example, below is the actual query where i am trying to fetch 1M records (main table POD has 22M records).

```
SELECT `some columns`
FROM `REALREMIT_PPIPFC_MIG`.MIGR_ORDER_DENORM MPO
INNER JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER_DETAILS POD 
ON MPO.PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PK=POD.PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PF
INNER JOIN PRODUCT PRD 
ON POD.PRODUCT_CODE_PF=PRD.PRODUCT_CODE_PK 
INNER JOIN EXPENSE_CODE EXP
ON PRD.EXPENSE_CODE_ID_FK=EXP.EXPENSE_CODE_ID_PK 
WHERE MPO.BATCH_ID=1;
```

Explain Output for the above query

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                       | key                        | key_len | ref                                                    | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PRD   | ALL    | PRIMARY,PRODUCT_EXCO_FK             | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                                                   | 14283 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | EXP   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                    | 4       | REALREMIT_PROD_ALTISOURCE.PRD.EXPENSE_CODE_ID_FK       |     1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | POD   | ref    | PRIMARY,RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PDCO_FK  | RMAPWBMS_PUOR_DETL_PDCO_FK | 34      | REALREMIT_PROD_ALTISOURCE.PRD.PRODUCT_CODE_PK          |    40 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MPO   | ref    | MIGR_PO_NBR_INDX,MIGR_BATCH_ID_INDX | MIGR_PO_NBR_INDX           | 4       | REALREMIT_PROD_ALTISOURCE.POD.PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PF |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```

> Both database have same charset
>   Columns used in join have the same collate
>   Both tables have same charset

I have created new table in which primary key is concatenated column - PURHCASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PF and PRODUCT_CODE_PF and then i have added a new index on PRODUCT_CODE_PF 
Will index be used in this case and/or is this the best way to make use of index in join.

Thanks

Comment: You have a phone book with all the people in your town. You want to call all of them. Is there any point referring to an index with people's names and last names, or is it just smarter to go page by page as you're trying to call all of them anyway? That's why your index is not used - it's just pointless, it does nothing. You're selecting all the records.

Comment: @N.B. - Please check the edit, i have added one more example which is having the same issue

Comment: MySQL optimizer is cost based and calculates what takes less time.. Random Disk I/O is expensive especially when you use normal HDD.. Don't know if the latest MySQL optimizer (8.0) optimizes with SSD better or can detect a SSD disk ..So MySQL chooses a FULL TABLE SCAN (1 Random Disk I/O and sequential read) over the index lookup (14283 Random Disk I/O) ...

Comment: ... Imagine if the seek time for a disk is 10ms. The full table scan will find this information in 10ms.. The index lookup would take 14283 * 10 = 142830ms thats 2.3805 minutes.. `EXPLAIN query FORMAT = JSON` will give a better insight off the costs needed to execute some different query plans (if your MySQL version supports is)

Comment: Is there even a problem? I mean, if this is slow, it's not due to the index not being used. Index helps *find* and *sort* the data. If you're selecting and sending 1M rows - the sheer amount of data being transferred and received is going to make this operation slow.

Comment: Yes, I want the index to get used for all the tables and see the performance, without full table scan of PRODUCT table, it would be required to read only 1 row from that table (Since PRODUCT_CODE_PK is primary key).  i am fine if it is still taking the same time after index getting used

Comment: But you're not reading what we're telling you.. you think that if index is used, that means your query is super cool and fast. That is not accurate. 10 minutes to select 1M records means that those records have to be found, read into the buffer, sent across the network, received. Index has _nothing_ to do with that here, it will not help you. Your second query doesn't use an index on purchase orders because it doesn't have to, there's no valid candidate and MySQL determined it's going to be slower. Why do you think index would help in reading and sending 1M rows? How would it do that?

Comment: @Viji78748 "it would be required to read only 1 row" indicates you are misinterpreting what MySQL is doing (and what everyone here is trying to tell you, so I try too). MySQL can reorder the joins (`a join b` = `b join a`). Your result has more than 1 product, so you obviously have to read more than 1 row from that table, and it is just a question of when you read them. Replace all `INNER JOIN` with `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, and `product` will use an index and `rows=1` - but now `mpo` won't. Since this specific join order was one of those MySQL considered but didn't use, it shouldn't be faster though.

Comment: @Viji78748 - "1 row" is "1 row _per row already fetched_".  Look at the `EXPLAIN`.  It estimates that the query will fetch 14283 rows from the first table, then _for each of those_, fetch 1 row from table 2.  (That's 14283 _random_ fetches from the table 2.  Then, for each of those 14283 rows, fetch 40 from table 3.  Etc.  The total is estimated at over **14283*1*40*1**.  (Caveat: the numbers are crude, and the interpretation is crude.)

Comment: @Viji78748 - The `EXPLAIN` shows a rather optimal plan.  Full table scan on table 1, then indexes for the other tables.

Comment: @Viji78748 - I would expect the Optimizer to start with `MPO` because of `WHERE MPO.BATCH_ID=1`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `MPO` and the other table involved.  _Then_ maybe we can further answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

These may help:

```
MPO:  INDEX(BATCH_ID, PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER_PK)   -- in this order
EXP:  INDEX(EXPENSE_CODE_ID_PK)   -- unless it is the PRIMARY KEY
```

But, without knowing what is in "some columns", I can't predict how much they will help.  And it would help to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for MPO and EXP.

How much RAM do you have? What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  I ask because you may be thrashing.